# How to read depth texture attached to FBO in WebGL2

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, webgl, webgl2

I'm now working on the deferred shading using WebGL2.0. One primary problem I'm now facing is that I can't read the depth value from the DEPTH_ATTACHMENT. Actually I creat my own GBuffer with a DEPTH24_STENCIL8 texture as DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, then I bind this texture to the sampler and try to read the value in my fragment shader in deferred shading part like this:

```
uniform sampler2D u_depthSampler;
vec4 depthValue = texture(u_depthSampler, v_uv);
```

Then I set the depthValue as output in my shading fragment shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 o_fragOut;
o_fragColor.xyz = depthValue.xyz;
o_fragColor.w = 1.0;
```

When doing this on firefox, it didn't report any error, but the output color is just pure red.(which means vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) I think). This really confuse me a lot. Can anyone provide some instruction? Is there any problem with my glsl code? THX~

Answer (score 2):

The depth buffer is not linear. To linearize it use this formula:

```
float f = 1000.0; //far plane
float n = 1.0; //near plane
float z = (2.0 * n) / (f + n - texture2D( diffuse, texCoord ).x * (f - n));

gl_FragColor = vec4(z,z,z, 255)
```

Comment: Exactly, I firstly thought that I got the wrong buffer, then I realize that the reason why mostly pixels tends to be **Pure Red** is that the depth buffer is non-linear, THX :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I may made a big mistake that the depth texture is acutually **nearly pure red** but not really red. I tried this:

```
float depthPow = pow(depthValue.x, 10.0);
o_fragOut.xyz = vec3(depthPow);
```

And I get the right result I think.